# What am I doing wrrong here that violates the rule that "order doesn't matter when multiplying and dividing?"

Tags: arithmetic

5 / 1 * 4

if I do the 5/1 first: 
(5 / 1) * 4
= 5 * 4 
= 20 (final answer is 20)

if I do the 1 * 4 first:
5/ (1 * 4) = 5/4 (final answer is 5/4)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no such rule.

Comment: Ah, whoops. Not sure how I got confused.

Comment: You do not distinguish between $\frac{5}{1}\cdot 4$ and $\frac{5}{1\cdot 4}$. These are two different things. In the first line you use the first form and in the second the second.

Comment: You can get rid of "division" if you think of it as the multiplication by the inverse of the number, i.e. instead of "dividing by 6" think of it as "multiplying by 1/6"...

Answer (score 1):

When you divide by 4, you are multiplying by 1/4.

Multiplication is commutative, which means that A.B = B.A, so 5*(1/4) = (1/4)*5.
However, division is clearly diferent, for 1/4 ≠ 4/1.
So in the first line you are multiplying (5/1)*4 = 5*4 = 20
In the second line its diferent, 5/ (1 * 4) = 5*(1/(1*4)) = 5*(1/4) = 5/4

Also, parentheses do matter a lot, for they clear what operations come first (operation priority). Multiplication and division have priority over sum and subtraction, but if you have a sum with parentheses , that comes first.
For example: A*(B+C) ≠  A*B+C, because the first one is A*(B+C) = A*B+A*C (Distributive property)

I hope I have helped. Saclyr.